# Django GeoIP Module Not Found

Tags: python, django, geolocation

I've spent several hours attempting to resolve my problems setting up GeoIP in Django to no avail and was hoping to get some guidance on what the problem(s) might be.

I'm working on an existing Django application that required some geolocation abilities, specifically getting a users IP and lat/long and then placing that info on a map marker. GeoIP and the associated libraries appeared to be the best solution for the first step.

I installed GeoIP on a Mac using Homebrew. I then manually created a folder in the root directory of my project with the GeoIPv6.data and GeoLiteCity.dat files. After this, I added the path in my settings file:

```
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

GEOIP_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'geoip'),
```

I then opened a command shell for the project and received the following error:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named geoip
```

I can't seem to remedy this problem. One issue that may be the cause is extracting the two dat.gz files was an issue. Neither could be unzipped from the command line – neither are .zip files – and had to use Stuffit Expander to open these. The resulting dat files in my project IDE (pyCharm) have a VLC (?) icon on each. Perhaps this is part of the issue (finding a way to uncompress the file was a challenge in itself). I'm not sure as the module was not even found.

Any help would be extremely appreciated in resolving this issue as I can't progress any further without figuring out what's wrong.

Many thanks.

*Edit. Okay, it first appeared an imroper import statement might have been the problem. Fixed it:        from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP. Unfortunately, once fixed, the following error results:

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/geoip.py", line 68, in <module>
    lgeoip = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/libGeoIP.dylib, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/local/lib/libGeoIP.dylib: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

This is perplexing. Not sure what the problem is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arch mismatch message means that the `libgeoIP` library you installed was built with a different CPU architecture than the architecture that the Python interpreter is running in.  From the paths involved, you appear to be using a newer (non-Apple-supplied) Python 2.7.  Chances are that the `libgeoIP` was built as 64-bit (`-arch x86_64`) while the Python you installed is a 32-bit -only Python 2.7 (`-arch i386`).  Or possibly the reverse.  In either case, you could try reinstalling GeoIP with the `universal` option so that it contains both archs.  Or you could try reinstalling Python 2.7 using a 64-bit/32-bit version such as downloadable from python.org.  You can see for sure which archs are involved by using the `file` command:

```
$ file /usr/local/lib/libGeoIP.dylib
$ file $(python2.7 -c 'import sys;print(sys.executable)')
```

There needs to be at least one common architecture between the two.

Comment: First, report back the output from those file commands to make sure you know what the situation really is.

Comment: Python:    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python (for architecture ppc):   Mach-O executable ppc
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386

Comment: GeoIP:/usr/local/lib/libGeoIP.dylib: symbolic link to ../Cellar/geoip/1.4.8/lib/libGeoIP.dylib    Apologies for not formatting in code; not sure how to do that in comments.

Comment: OK, sorry, it's a symlink so that second one doesn't really help: you need to do a file on that full path shown. But the first output does confirm that you are using a 32-bit-only Python 2.7.  Chances are the output from the file libGeoIP.dylib will show `x86_64`.  I'm not a `brew` user, but I believe you can install a universal version  by adding the `--universal` keyword to the brew command, so something like `brew install --universal geoip`

Comment: Thanks, Ned. So I assume this means I need to uninstall the old version, correct, before attempting to install the new one. Apologies for the amateurish questions but this is my first Django project and I fall into the weeds like this now and then. Learning as I go.

Comment: Well, we're a step forward and two back. I uninstalled and reinstalled with the universal geoIP. I then ran the shell and it started to work until I assigned GeoIp to a variable per the Django docs:>>> from django.contrib.gis.utils.geoip import GeoIP
>>> g = GeoIP()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/utils/geoip.py", line 193, in __init__
    raise TypeError('Invalid path type: %s' % type(path).__name__)
TypeError: Invalid path type: tuple

Comment: Glad to have answered your initial question.  Sorry, I'm not a geoip user.  Suggest you open a new question about your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to import GeoIP on Django 1.4 and up (including the current 1.9 release) is:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue with your dat files. Its a problem with the import statement, and it finding the GeoIP module.

From the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/

> In Django 1.4, the GeoIP object was moved out of
>   django.contrib.gis.utils and into its own module,
>   django.contrib.gis.geoip. A shortcut is still provided in utils, but
>   will be removed in Django 1.6.

If you are using django 1.3.x, try:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
```

Note the difference in the import paths between these two versions:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/gis/geoip/

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense but unfortunately, a new error is resulting:      >>> from django.contrib.gis.utils import GeoIP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name GeoIP      Any idea what this could be?

Comment: @Why Not: are you sure you followed the GeoDjango doc and installed the maxmind geoip properly? Seems its built incorrectly.

Comment: I installed it with Brew and it had some problems with permissions and links, but those were fixed with a script. In looking around, it seems this might be because I'm using a 64-bit Python build instead of a 32.bit. Not sure. Would appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0):

```
Previously i was facing this issue : from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP ImportError: cannot import name GeoIP
```

Solution :

```
yum install GeoIP-devel -y
```